# Can I kill someone without shooting him in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

It has happened to me twice that I kill someone without doing anything to him. I just go running and I pass by him and he dies, but I earn the death score. Why does this happen? Is there any kind of damage from collision or something? This is playing multiplayer modes.

Comment: is it at all possible you were just pressing the melee attack button enough to trigger it ? Otherwise its impossible theres no damage created by just running into another player.

Comment: After reading the initial question, I thought "sure, there are lots of ways that you can kill someone. Vehicles, melee, explosives, trapping them in a collapsing building" but I'm not sure of being able to kill someone without doing anything at all to them. Sounds like a bug or a glitch to me.

Comment: @Zissouu nope I'm more sure that I did not make any attack and less melee. I just ran and when I turned the corner I passed close to the enemy player and he dies. hahaha as crazy as it sounds. And I tell you, it has happened more than once

Comment: I must clarify that I am almost sure that the other player has always come to me running too. Is it possible that some kind of collision damage is generated?

Comment: If I had to guess there is some sort of collision damage that happens when breaking the hitbox but thats just a guess it really sounds  like a glitch more then anything or else this would be fairly well documented seeing the amount of time bf3's been out.